# Positioning svg icons for slider

Tags: css, svg

I've just got started with svg images and I am struggling with this.

I'm trying to make the svg image white with a red circle background when the class is selected.

Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/digitalk/0L8nc3pu/2/

I can't seem to get the circle and cross aligned

```
.pagination {
    position:relative;
}
.pagination ul {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:50px;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
            transform: translateX(-50%);



}
.pagination ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    height:10px;
    width:10px;
    padding:10px;
}
.selected {
    background:rgb(192,0,0);
    height:10px;
    width:10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.dave path {
    fill: #76665e !important;   
}
 .selected .dave path {
    fill: white !important;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You have a lot of stuff in that fiddle. Would it be possible to trim it down a bit to the minimum code that still produces your error?

Comment: Sure, give me a minute